# How to add each word or get string as separate entry to database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, explode

```
$stuffname=$_GET['stuffname'];
$pieces = explode(" ", $stuffname);
```

$pieces can have any number of words in it.

I want to loop this query so that each word is added from pieces as a separate entry into the table keywords

```
$query=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO keywords (stuffname) VALUES (?)");
$query->execute([$pieces]);
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if you've tried anything or where you got stuck, but this should be very simple with a loop.

Either

1. execute a separate INSERT for each new row

```
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO keywords (stuffname) VALUES (?)");

    foreach ($pieces as $piece)
      $query->execute([$piece]);{
    }
```

or

2. Try to build a single INSERT with multiple sets of values:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO keywords (stuffname) VALUES ";
    $vals = "";
    
    foreach ($pieces as $piece)
    {
      $vals .= ($vals != "" ? "," : "")."(?)";
    }
    
    $query = $con->prepare($sql.$vals);
    $query->execute([$pieces]);
```

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks, corrected :-)